# Changing instance of Feature on click

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

Im trying to find a way to change the instance of a Leaflet geoJson Feature after it is added to the map.

This is what I want to achieve:

Importing data with L.GeoJson and I am using `pointToLayer` to change the marker to `L.CircleMarker`

Now I want

```
layer.on('click', function (e) {
   e.target //Do something here to change it from L.CircleMarker to L.Marker
});
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var group = L.geoJSON(); // Your geojson group on importing
layer.on('click', function (e) {
   var circlemarker = e.target //Do something here to change it from L.CircleMarker to L.Marker
   var marker = L.marker(circlemarker.getLatLng()).addTo(group);
   marker.feature = circlemarker.feature
   circlemarker.removeFrom(group)
   // Then add the same events to the layer as in pointToLayer
});
```

Comment: If i add the
marker.on('click', onLayerClick);

and try to fire it instantly to make user not need to do a click again
marker.fire('click')

It does not work as expected.

If i make the user click it a second time it works as expected. Any idea why?

Comment: No is hard to say without demo code. But why you not calling `onLayerClick({target:marker})` directly?